# Custom vertex in graph that have external ring around it as a menu

Tags: reactjs, web, graph, vertex

I want custom web based graph with edge and vertex that have external ring around each node as a menu.
this menu can have multiple choice as sections like radial graph.
user must be able to select a node then menus shown as a ring around that and then based on user selection the graph expanded.

I use React as a platform but if you have any suggestion in other technologies there's no problem to use that. for example I find Reagraph component but there are several error with right to left fonts.
also I see Graph-tool with python but I don't know that cover my need or not?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).